# Change woocommerce error messages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to change the text of the error message that occurs on the checkout page when a customer hasn't filled in all the required fields. Currnetly, the message will display EVERY field that needs to be filled in, for example:
"Billing address is a required field.
Billing postal code is q required field.
Email address is a required field.
..."

I would like just ONE message that says "Please fill in the required field." or, if more than one field needs to be filled in "Please fill in the required fields."

Does anyone know how to dy this? My PHP is limited.
Thanks!

Comment: This multi-faceted question includes no coding attempt and should be narrowed.  If your PHP skills are too "limited", please hire a PHP developer instead of using the volunteer base on Stack Overflow to do what they should be paid for.

Answer (score 3):

**Updated Code:**

Add this code in function.php file:

```
function my_woocommerce_add_error( $error ) {
    if (strpos($error,'required') !== false) {
        $error = 'Required';
    }
    return $error;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_error', 'my_woocommerce_add_error' );
```

and add this code in notices\error.php file:

```
<ul class="woocommerce-error">
    <?php 
    $totalReq = count(array_keys($messages, 'Required')); 
    $removeReq = array_diff($messages, ["Required"]);

    if($totalReq > 1){
        echo '<li>Please fill in all the <strong>required</strong> fields.</li>';
    }else{
        echo '<li>Please fill in the <strong>required</strong> field.</li>';
    }
    ?>
    <?php foreach ( $removeReq as $message ) : ?>
        <li><?php echo wp_kses_post( $message ); ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Hope it will resolve your concern :)

Comment: Hi, thanks, but this changes ALL the error messages, even the ones that don't have anything to do with required fields...but I only need to change this one specific error message.

Comment: so for only required fields you need that one message? other messages should be intact?

Comment: Only for the error message that is displayed on the checkout page when the customer hasn't filled out all the fields, so NOT when the customer wants to add a product to the cart that is sold out for example(there are lots of Woocommerce error messages).

Comment: then you can count only required error messages using strpos and add filter in function.php.

Comment: No, unfortunately it does not work. The regular message is still showing up.

Comment: No, it will not show any required messages. i have tested it.

Comment: I also tried it, but the regular error message shows up when you click on "place order" without having filled in any of the required fields.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working nice for general required error message display. But it depends language of website too for searching string 'required' in strpos function, that needs to be change based on your website language.

Also in code for error template file needs to change from

```
$removeReq = array_diff($messages, ["Required"]);
```

to

```
$removeReq = array_diff($messages, array("Required"));
```

Than it works like a charm.
Nice idea to overwrite error messages. Non of the solutions found for this yet, but this works really good.

But it works on all woocommerce forms like edit address from my account page, etc..